# Application running issue in android emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I am trying to run an app in android emulator which has GPU Emulation enabled.My app was working fine, but suddenly it stopped working and I can see this message in stack trace:

```
07-13 17:05:17.011: E/EGL_emulation(1437): rcMakeCurrent returned EGL_FALSE
07-13 17:05:17.024: E/EGL_emulation(1437): tid 1450: eglMakeCurrent(952): error 0x3006 (EGL_BAD_CONTEXT)
```

Anyone faced this problem, please share your solution if anything you have.Thanks

Comment: Try restarting your Eclipse, sir.

Comment: @JetPro Eclipse restarted and also system restarted.

Comment: Try updating your Android SDK Tools to revision 20.

Comment: Yes i tried already, but no success.

Comment: Does your app use GoogleMaps API or libs, compiled for ARM (not x86)?

Comment: @AndroidKiller What video card do you have?

Comment: i used x86.it is needed for my app.no my app doesnot use google maps.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your emulator set target with CPU/ABI:Intel Atom(x86). To create it you should update Android SDK Manager - install "Intel x86 Atom System image" and to accelerate: extras/"Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager"

Comment: I am updating intel x86 Atom System Image. Second one is not compatible Linux.Let's see.